# It seems executor and rabbitConnectionFactory are conflicting during bean creation in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm experiencing a conflict between the Executor

I'm using in Spring Boot and the rabbitConnectionFactory in RabbitAutoConfiguration.

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor1")
    public Executor asyncExecutor1() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'asyncExecutor1' defined in class path resource []: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.concurrent.Executor]: Illegal arguments to factory method 'asyncExecutor1'; args: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:264)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:221)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.destroy(NamedContextFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:596)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
```

If you modify the code like this, it should run without any errors and function properly.

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I wonder what difference this code makes and why.

Please also tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Have you looked at `AsyncConfigurer` source code? Because that’s where the answer lies.

Comment: Is it desirable to override the getAsyncExecutor method?